# how to search without string data?

Tags: string, vb.net, ms-access

```
  Try
        Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath + "\TPDB.accdb"
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(str)
```

how to search without string data?

```
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from TestLists where T_Name like " + Des1.Text + "", con)
```

Error this msg "syntax error in group by clause."

```
        Dim adpt As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet() 

        adpt.Fill(ds, "TestLists")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)



        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index
        Amnt1.Text = DataGridView2.Item(2, i).Value 


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Use parameters...and you are missing `'%` and `%'` in your command around like statement.

Comment: Do not construct queries by concatenation. Use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access uses * as the wildchar, and qoutes are missing, thus it could be:

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from TestLists where T_Name like '*" + Des1.Text + "*'", con)
```